# How to check if a context request path starts with a given string from a list of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http

I have multiple if statements here which would check if a request path starts with a given string and return true if the condition is met

```
if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/abc/def", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
 {  return true; }
if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/pqr/xyz", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
 {  return true; }
```

and so on with few more if statements....

How do I optimize this and create a list of such values ("/abc/def") where it would just iterate through the list and return true if the condition is met?

Comment: You can use the String.StartsWith Method method. For more usage, please refer to the documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) with the list of expected path,

```
var expectedPath = new List<string>(){"/abc/def", "/pqr/xyz"};

return expectedPath.Any(x => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: I saw the bracket typo!

Comment: @JeremyThompson I fixed it before your comment. Any way thanks for your observation. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `Array.Exists()` method for checking path is `expectedPath` array.

```
    string[] expectedPath = {"/abc/def", "/pqr/xyz"};
    Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists(expectedPath, element => emlement == StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists(expectedPath, element => element =="/abc/def")); // this will return true
    Console.WriteLine(Array.Exists(expectedPath, element => element =="A")); //this is return false
```